# Crawl iterating with a parameter over a list of urls from a rule with Scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm a newbie on Scrapy and Python. I want to do the following:

1. Access to an url and get all the links **containing "shop/products"** as part of the url. The links look like: "[http://www.example.com/shop/products/*category-name*](http://www.example.com/shop/products/_category-name_)"
2. Scrap an url of start_urls and get the number of total products, **TOTAL**. On the code TOTAL = **num_items_per_category**.
3. At the end, add **"?sort=Top&size=12&start=*PARAM*"** to the url. PARAM must be incremented by 12 on each iteration just in case PARAM <= TOTAL. The final url would be "[http://www.example.com/shop/products/*category-name*?sort=Top&size=12&start=*PARAM*](http://www.example.com/shop/products/_category-name_?sort=Top&size=12&start=_PARAM_)"
4. Get another url from the start_urls generated and start step 2 again.

---

Here is my spider code:

```
import scrapy
import re
import datetime

from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.http.request import Request

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'my_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/shop/products']
    rules = (
        Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(
            restrict_xpaths=('.//li[@class="item"]/a')),
            follow=False,
            callback='parse_list'
        ),
     )

    def parse_list(self, response):
        SET_SELECTOR = '.product'
        for item in response.css(ITEM_SELECTOR):
            NAME_SELECTOR = 'div[@class="product"]/h2/a/@title'
            yield {
                'name': item.xpath(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first()
            }

        NUM_ITEMS_PER_CATEGORY_SELECTOR = 'div[@id="search"]/@data-count'
        num_items_per_category = item.xpath(NUM_ITEMS_PER_CATEGORY_SELECTOR).extract_first()
        nipc = int(0 if num_items_per_category is None else num_items_per_category)
        try:
            next_start = response.meta["next_start"]
        except KeyError:
            next_start = 0
        if next_start <= nipc:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                response.urljoin('%s?sort=Top&size=12&start=%s' % (response.url, next_start)),
                meta={"next_start": next_start + 12},
                dont_filter=True,
                callback = self.parse_list
            )
```

---

Problems are:

1. I don't know if it exists any css selector or regex to use in a Rule to select every link I want. On the code, I'm accessing to a path where I know there are some of my wanted links, but still there are more on the page.
2. The code is not working as I'm expecting. It seems **next_start** is not incrementing by 12 on each iteration. The code are getting just the first 12 elements of each url on the start_urls list generated. Am I using *meta* variables correctly? Or may be I need another first scrap of each category page to get the TOTAL count before I can use it to iterate over it? Or maybe I need another approach using **start_requests**... What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your spider exactly does is visits the url `http://www.example.com/shop/products`, extracts all the links inside `<li class="item">` elements and fetches all of them using `parse_list` callback. As I see it is not the behavior you're awaiting for - instead you should use some start url containing seeding URLs and Extractor with `allow=r"shop/products"` in the Rule.

Also this part `'%s?sort=Top&size=12&start=%s' % (response.url, next_start)` is wrong because response.url contains full URL including GET parameters, thus every time you append the part with parameters to existing parameters string like this `?sort=Top&size=12&start=0?sort=Top&size=12&start=12?sort=Top&size=12&start=24`. Clean up parameters from url before appending new string or just use `FormRequest` as more convenient way to pass parameters.

By the way Scrapy has very handy interactive console for debugging purposes which you can invoke from any part of spider using `scrapy.shell.inspect_response`.

Comment: Thanks, mizhgun! That's exactly what is happening! I will play with the debbuger to test that kind of things.